# Adding fb:admin to D7 theme head?

Tags: facebook, drupal, drupal-7, head

```
function Newbiovasa_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
    drupal_set_html_head('<meta property="fb:admins" content="188890209211"/>');
    $vars['head'] = drupal_get_html_head();  
}
```

Have tried this but it renders page to server error 500. Im trying to add fb:admins to page because like box gives error when trying to like page. It does like and share but doesnt increase amount of likes.

The page failed to provide a valid list of administrators. It needs to specify the administrators using either a "fb:app_id" meta tag, or using a "fb:admins" meta tag to specify a comma-delimited list of Facebook users.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `drupal_set_html_head()` function in Drupal 7, I'd put my money on that being the cause of the white screen.

You're probably looking for [`drupal_add_html_head()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7).

Comment: Thanks, I will check if Im able to sort it. Not php coder by any means.